# C++ Template Specialization with Inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Following Situation:

```
class FeatureBase
class Feature1 : public FeatureBase

class FeatureAttrBase
class Feature1Attr : public FeatureAttrbase
```

FeatureBase contains a list of FeatureAttrBase and should be able to create and manage these objects. Therefore i use a template on FeatureBase.

```
template<class T = FeatureAttrBase> class FeatureBase
```

creating and managing the attributes (e.g. new T())

and the subclasses use a specialized inheritance

```
class Feature1 : public FeatureBase<Feature1Attr>
```

Anywhere else in my code i wrote a method

```
RegisterFeature(FeatureBase<FeatureAttrBase>* feature)
```

but the compiler gives me an error that it was unable to convert between Feature1 and FeatureBase. In the mentioned method i only need to use information from FeatureAttrBase. But inside Feature1 i need access to Feature1Attr.

Thus the question is how to solve this issue? Do i have to change my datastructure?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: `Feature1` and `FeatureBase<FeatureAttrBase>` do not belong to the same hierarchy, they're unrelated classes.

Comment: is there a possibility to change the hierarchy (template, inheritance) to use the classes in the mentioned way?

Answer (score 1):

Having template parameters inherit from each other doesn't make template classes related. You should instead do something like the following (might not be the best solution but you haven't specified what you are trying to do):

```
class FeatureAttrBase;
class FeatureBase
{
public:
    virtual FeatureAttrBase* GetAttributes() = 0;
};

template<class T>
class FeatureImpl : public FeatureBase
{
    T attr;
public:
    FeatureAttrBase* GetAttributes()
    {
        return &attr;
    }
};

class Feature1Attr : public FeatureAttrBase;
class Feature1 : public FeatureImpl<Feature1Attr>;
```

In fact, you probably don't need the `FeatureImpl` class and can put the implementation directly in the `Feature1` class (and get rid of templates completely).

Comment: Okay. This is my specification: I have several Features each having a list of attributes related to some objects in the environment. All attributes have a common base (FeatureAttbase). Thus the special attributes (Feature1Attr) can be updated inside of a Feature. But also a more general algorithm runs over all the Features and reads the common values to calculate an overall result.

Comment: What is the reason for separating Feature and FeatureAttr? Either way, my solution should be okay, and you can get rid of the `FeatureImpl` class as its not really doing anything - just store a `Feature1Attr` inside `Feature1` and have it return its pointer in `GetAttributes`.

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit the specialisations of `FeatureBase` from `FeatureBase<FeatureAttrBase>`. Something like this:

```
// Forward declaration
template <typename T>
class FeatureBase;

// Type selecting trait class FeatureBase_BaseClass
// FeatureBase for derived Attrs will inherit from FeatureBase<FeatureAttrBase>
template <typename T>
struct FeatureBase_BaseClass
{
  typedef FeatureBase<FeatureAttrBase> Type;
};

// FeatureBase<FeatureAttrBase> will inherit from a dummy type
template <>
struct FeatureBase_BaseClass<FeatureAttrBase>
{
  struct Type {};
};



// Use FeatureBase_BaseClass to select the proper base class for FeatureBase
template <typename T = FeatureAttrBase>
class FeatureBase : public FeatureBase_BaseClass<T>::Type
{
  //as before
};
```

This way, all `FeatureBase<X>` for specific attributes `X` will inherit from `FeatureBase<FeatureAttrBase>`.